# Can punctured tires be made tubeless?

Tags: tubeless

I have tubeless-ready tires and tubeless-ready wheels but a non-tubeless setup. I've had two punctures on each wheel and am tired of having to change inner-tubes, so I am considering converting to tubeless.

Is it likely there will be any problems caused by the fact my tire was previously punctured? Will it make any difference at all?

Specs are as follows:

Rims:
WTB ST i23 TCS, 28h, tubeless ready

Tires:
WTB Riddler TCS Light, 700 x 37c, tubeless ready

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on the size of the puncture, of course.

If you only had small punctures, that would be clogged by sealant in a tubeless setup, no reason that sealant wouldn't clog them afterwards.

Seating the tires may be a more complicated though, since you would need to pump faster given that there will be additional leaks and you will need to compensate.

Comment: Not my area, but the tyres should have taken a set from being seated before, even with tubes on the inside, no?  I do remember that using a tube for a day was one way to help make a stubborn tubeless tyre conform to the wheel before trying to seat it tubeless.

Comment: Though, if the tire is being remounted no reason not to fix the punctures with boots rather than just relying on sealant.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a "bacon strip" or even better, a proper motorcycle/automotive-style tubeless patch to help seal the puncture. That would provide a more permanent fix than simply relying on the congealed sealant alone.